# Android ContentValues weird Out of scope removal

Tags: android, sqlite

In a view of my application I can re-sort the position of the rows of a ListView by drag & drop and I save the new order of the rows in the database. The ListView Shows the the contents of an ArrayList defined this way:

```
ArrayList<ContentValues> lstBat;
```

and it is populated from a SQLite database. After populate the list I add some values to the "ContentValues" that I use in the Array adapter.

The problem comes in the re_sort method after execute "dbTools.updateBat(cv)".

```java
public void re_sort() {
    int lines= lstBat.size();
    ContentValues cv=null;
    for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
        cv = lstBat.get(i); //get row's cv
        cv.put("order", i); //Assign new order
        dbTools.updateBat(cv); //Store new order in the list
        lstBat.set(i, cv);
    }
}
```

The values "state", "icon" and "date" are no longer in the local variable "cv"  (ContentValues), they were removed too !!!!!

updateBat method is defined in DBTools class

```java
public int updateBat (ContentValues cv){
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    cv.remove("state"); //Not a column of the table
    cv.remove("icon"); //Not a column of the table
    cv.remove("date"); //Not a column of the table
    return database.update(TABLE_bat, cv, "batId"+"=?", new String[]{cv.getAsString("batId")});
}
```

And this is the workaround:

```java
public void re_sort() {
    int lines= lstBat.size();
    long date=0;
    String state="";
    int icon=0;
    ContentValues cv=null;
    for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
        cv = lstBat.get(i);
        date=cv.getAsLong("date");
        icon=cv.getAsInteger("icon");
        state=cv.getAsString("state");
        cv.put("order", i);
        dbTools.updateBat(cv);
        cv.put("state",state);
        cv.put("icon",icon);
        cv.put("date",date);
        lstBat.set(i, cv);
    }
}
```

If I comment out dbTools.updateBat(cv) the values are preserved, and of course the database won't be updated.

## Why were they removed if they are out of scope?

Comment: Why are you calling  cv.remove("state");?

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your code, its behavior seems quite normal.

From your `re_sort` method you pass the `cv` object to the `updateBat` method. All object parameters in Java are passed **by reference**, therefore `cv` is NOT a copy of your original object. If you wish to pass a copy of your `ContentValues` object, you should create a clone. Something like this:

```
public void re_sort() {
    int lines= lstBat.size();
    ContentValues cv=null;
    for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
        cv = lstBat.get(i); //get row's cv
        cv.put("order", i); //Assign new order
        dbTools.updateBat(new ContentValues(cv)); //Store new order in the list, by passing a new ContentValues object
        lstBat.set(i, cv);
    }
}
```